# Android keyboard Issue?

Tags: android, keyboard, case, cpu-word

Every keyboard app has auto capitalization of first letter of each sentence feature in settings,  but I want to put first letter of each word also. I have changed android:inputType = textCapSentences into textCapWords everywhere but still keyboard is typing in sentence case.

Please help me!

Thank you in advance.

Help with the android keyboard issue, Please

Comment: There is no requirement for any soft keyboard implementation to support either of those `inputType` options. `inputType` is a request, not a command.

Comment: Please Help Me How Do I Add Auto-Capitalisation Of First Letter Of Each Word In My Keyboard Under Settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I Want My Keyboard Type Like This Automatically Without Hitting Shift All Time